# React component not working on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've made an knob which can be dragged to adjust the value. It is working fine when using a mouse but I can get it to work on a touchscreen. I've looked arround for some solutions like touch-action and pointer in CSS but these dont work. What else could I do to make this work because I cant really find something on SO either.

This is the knob component.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Knob extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fullAngle = props.degrees;
    this.startAngle = (360 - props.degrees) / 2;
    this.endAngle = this.startAngle + props.degrees;
    this.margin = props.size * 0.15;
    this.currentDeg = Math.floor(
      this.convertRange(
        props.min,
        props.max,
        this.startAngle,
        this.endAngle,
        props.value
      )
    );
    this.state = { deg: this.currentDeg };
  }

  startDrag = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const knob = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const pts = {
      x: knob.left + knob.width / 2,
      y: knob.top + knob.height / 2
    };
    const moveHandler = e => {
      this.currentDeg = this.getDeg(e.clientX, e.clientY, pts);
      if (this.currentDeg === this.startAngle) this.currentDeg--;
      let newValue = Math.floor(
        this.convertRange(
          this.startAngle,
          this.endAngle,
          this.props.min,
          this.props.max,
          this.currentDeg
        )
      );
      this.setState({ deg: this.currentDeg });
      this.props.onChange(newValue);
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler);
    });
  };

  getDeg = (cX, cY, pts) => {
    const x = cX - pts.x;
    const y = cY - pts.y;
    let deg = Math.atan(y / x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    if ((x < 0 && y >= 0) || (x < 0 && y < 0)) {
      deg += 90;
    } else {
      deg += 270;
    }
    let finalDeg = Math.min(Math.max(this.startAngle, deg), this.endAngle);
    return finalDeg;
  };

  convertRange = (oldMin, oldMax, newMin, newMax, oldValue) => {
    return (oldValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin) / (oldMax - oldMin) + newMin;
  };

  renderTicks = () => {
    let ticks = [];
    const incr = this.fullAngle / this.props.numTicks;
    const size = this.margin + this.props.size / 2;
    for (let deg = this.startAngle; deg <= this.endAngle; deg += incr) {
      const tick = {
        deg: deg,
        tickStyle: {
          height: size + 10,
          left: size - 1,
          top: size + 2,
          transform: "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
          transformOrigin: "top"
        }
      };
      ticks.push(tick);
    }
    return ticks;
  };

  dcpy = o => {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
  };

  render() {
    let kStyle = {
      width: this.props.size,
      height: this.props.size
    };
    let iStyle = this.dcpy(kStyle);
    let oStyle = this.dcpy(kStyle);
    oStyle.margin = this.margin;
    if (this.props.color) {
      oStyle.backgroundImage =
        "radial-gradient(100% 70%,hsl(210, " +
        this.currentDeg +
        "%, " +
        this.currentDeg / 5 +
        "%),hsl(" +
        Math.random() * 100 +
        ",20%," +
        this.currentDeg / 36 +
        "%))";
    }
    iStyle.transform = "rotate(" + this.state.deg + "deg)";

    return (
      <div className="knob" style={kStyle}>
        <div className="ticks">
          {this.props.numTicks
            ? this.renderTicks().map((tick, i) => (
                <div
                  key={i}
                  className={
                    "tick" + (tick.deg <= this.currentDeg ? " active" : "")
                  }
                  style={tick.tickStyle}
                />
              ))
            : null}
        </div>
        <div className="knob outer" style={oStyle} onMouseDown={this.startDrag}>
          <div className="knob inner" style={iStyle}>
            <div className="grip" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the stylesheet:

```
.knob {
  touch-action: manipulation;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.knob .ticks {
  position: absolute;
}
.knob .ticks .tick {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 black;
  width: 3px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
.knob .ticks .tick.active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px #509eec, 0 0 0 1px #369;
}
.knob.outer {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #222;
  background: radial-gradient(closest-side, #666 6%, #333 90%);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 2px black, 0 0 5px 3px black, 0 0 0 12px #444;
}
.knob.inner {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.knob.inner .grip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #509eec;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For touch devices, you can use `onTouchStart` for the same events as `onMouseDown`.

Also, you might be interested in `onPointerDown` events which will work on both touch and non touch devices. [Check browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer)